# Inserir elementos aleatórios em um array em Java Script

Tags: javascript

Suponhamos que eu tenho o seguinte array:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7]
```

Se eu quiser acrescentar o numero 3 na posição 02 do array eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
const add = arr.splice(2,0, 3)
console.log(arr)
```

A pergunta é: Qual a melhor forma de acrescentar também o número 6 no posição 4 do array nesta mesma `const add`

Comment: O "número 6 na posição 4" não é bem um "elemento aleatório", como comentou no título. O que queria dizer com "elementos aleatórios"?

Comment: Vale lembrar que [`splice` retorna um array com os elementos deletados](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value). Mas como você passa zero no segundo parâmetro, nenhum elemento é deletado, então `add` sempre será um array vazio (ou seja, neste trecho de código essa variável parece desnecessária - a menos, é claro, que o código esteja em um contexto maior no qual o retorno seja relevante, aí faz sentido guardá-lo em uma variável)

Answer (score 1):

Assim:

```
 arr.splice(2, 0, 3, 4)
```

Você também pode fazer assim:

```
const array = [3, 4]

arr.splice(2, 0, ...array)
```

Comment: Lucas o problema é que os novos itens são inseridos em índices distintos. Se o problema fosse inserir `n` itens em um índice específico sua solução seria perfeita.

Answer (score 1):

Um loop resolverá seu problema visto que os itens inseridos no array ficam em posições diferentes:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7]

// Adicione a [[posição1, valor1], [posição2, valor2]...]
const data = [[2, 3], [5, 6]];
data.forEach(a => arr.splice(a[0], 0, a[1]));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Show!!! Certinho muito obrigado!!! Seria possível fazer isso percorrendo o array com o método map()?

Comment: @SenaOliveira é possível mas não sei se é a melhor escolha. Exemplo: `[[2, 3], [5, 6]].map(a => arr.splice(a[0], 0, a[1]));` O `map` retorna um array como resultado após processar cada item do array de origem. Como você não precisa deste retorno não sei se é o mais indicado. Acredito que o `forEach` é o mais indicado para este problema

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado pela explicação!!!

Comment: @SenaOliveira `map` só faz sentido se vc quer transformar todos os elementos do array em outra coisa. Mas neste caso vc está inserindo elementos no array, e não transformando os valores existentes, então `map` não faz sentido nesse caso

Comment: @hkotsubo Show, muito obrigado pela dica!!!